# Cos'è una "falciuola"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> I suoi alberi ora erano addobbati di fogli scritti e anche di cartelli con massime di Seneca e Shaftesbury, e di oggetti: ciuffi di penne, ceri da chiesa, **falciuole**, corone, busti da donna, pistole, bilance, legati l’uno all’altro in un certo ordine.

Potreste spiegarmi cos'è una "falciuola"?
Non ho trovato questo termine in nessuno dei dizionari monolingui italiani che ho consultato, ma curiosamente appare in questo [dizionario francese italiano dell'Ottocento](https://books.google.es/books?id=kZMKAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=falciuola+significato&source=bl&ots=YpcW4MhAVa&sig=HnuJkjMWIGxDNA9NtJb6KLxFtzQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCm_v-8qraAhVBnhQKHUPGBoAQ6AEIDzAC#v=onepage&q=falciuola%20significato&f=false), dal quale sembra si tratti di qualche "strumento per segare le biade".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

È un diminutivo di [falce](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/falce/)

> ◆ I dim. falcétto, falcino, falciòlo (letter. falciuòlo) e l’accr.
>   falcióne (v.), tutti masch., indicano spesso falci di forme
>   particolari.

ed indica appunto una piccola falce ricurva usata principalmente per tagliare l’erba che i contadini portavano legata alla cintura.

Anche sull’Accademia della Crusca si trova per  [falciuola](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=FALCIUOLA&rewrite=1)

> FALCIUOLA. Definiz: Dim. di Falce. Lat. falcula. Gr. δρεπάνιον.
>   Esempio: Fr. Giord. Pred. Lo scalzo villanello in tempo di messura
>   colla sua falciuola si procaccia il vivere.

Ecco un’immagine della falciuola:

[image: falciuola o falciola]

Comment: Forse, come sembra accennare il Treccani, si tratta di una piccola falce con una forma particolare?

Comment: Come vedi dall’immagine aggiunta è una piccola falce ricurva utile per tagliare erba, ed anche per tagliare piccoli rami.